# Write table different directory

Tags: r

I am trying to write multiple files in a different directory to the one the R script is contained. If I write them in the same directory it works but in a different one it does not produce any output.. Here is the code

```
list    <- split(datainK, list(datainK$name), drop = TRUE)
filenames <- paste("~/DIR", names(list), ".dat")
filenames <- sapply(filenames,gsub,pattern=" .dat",replacement=".dat")
mapply(write.table, list, file = filenames,col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your filenames is not well defined.

Replace

```
filenames <- paste("~/DIR", names(list), ".dat")
```

by

```
filenames <- paste0("~/DIR/",names(list), ".dat")
```

Comment: When I am using past0 an error occurs : Error: could not find function "paste0"

Comment: @ user2287387 `paste0` is a shorcut to `paste` by setting `sep=""` as in `paste(..., sep = "", collapse)`, therefore if `paste0` throws an error, change and use `paste` setting `sep=""`. Note that `paste` has by default `sep=" "` and `paste0` has `sep=""` with no space.

Comment: amazing that `paste0` throw an error...Which R version are you using ?